# Regex exec function not returning correct result in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, function

I am trying to write a function which will parse a string in the form of `7:55am - 9:10am (TR) 8:10am - 9:00am (W)` and output a multi dimensional ]array containing the regex result (ex `[[7:55am, 9:10am, TR], [7:55am, 9:00am, W]]`)

This is my function as it currently stands:

```
function parseClassTime(times) {
    console.log("Input: " + times);
    var timeArr = [];
    var finalArr = [];
    regexStr = /(\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m) - (\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m) \((\w{1,5})\)/g;
    if (times.indexOf(") ") > -1) {
        times = times.replace(") ", ")&");
        timeArr = times.split("&");
    } else {
        timeArr.push(times);
    }
    console.log("timeArr: " + timeArr);
    for (i = 0; i < timeArr.length; i++) {
        console.log(i + ":" + timeArr[i]);
        console.log("regexResult: " + regexStr.exec(timeArr[i]));
    }
};
```

And this is the output that I am getting:

```
Input: 7:55am - 9:10am (TR) 8:10am - 9:00am (W)
timeArr: 7:55am - 9:10am (TR),8:10am - 9:00am (W)
0:7:55am - 9:10am (TR)
regexResult: 7:55am - 9:10am (TR),7:55am,9:10am,TR
1:8:10am - 9:00am (W)
regexResult: null
```

For the life of me I cannot discover where that `null` is coming from. Does something happen to the regex string between the two calls to `.exec()`?

Please let me know your thoughts!

Comment: Just change `{0,5}` to `{1,5}`. I think it's matching for zero length too.

Comment: First, you have `am` and `pm` dangling, use `[ap]m`, then - as the comment above states - `{0,5}` can match 0 characters. Try `(\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m) - (\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m) \((\w+)\)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys! I changed it however I am still getting a null value

Comment: There is an issue with the code.

Comment: Should the loop's upper limit be array.length-1 ?

Comment: Check [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2hgkjh3c/)

Comment: Thanks for the demo! It works perfectly. I still wonder what I did wrong above. I think I might not understand completely how .exec() works

Comment: It is just how `exec` works: the lastIndex property got set to `20` after the first match. You did not reset it. The second time, it could not match anything as it started looking for a match at Position 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just how `[RegExp.exec()][1]` works: the `lastIndex` property got set to 20 after the first match and you did not reset it. The second time, it could not match anything as it started looking for a match at Position 20.  This all happens this way because the regex is built with the global modifier `/g`.

> If your regular expression uses the `"g"` flag, you can use the `exec()` method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the search starts at the substring of `str` specified by the regular expression's [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) property

You can reset the `regexStr.lastIndex` manually:

```js
function parseClassTime(times) {
    console.log("Input: " + times);
    var timeArr = [];
    var finalArr = [];
    regexStr = /(\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m) - (\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m) \((\w{1,5})\)/g;
    if (times.indexOf(") ") > -1) {
        times = times.replace(") ", ")&");
        timeArr = times.split("&");
    } else {
        timeArr.push(times);
    }
    console.log("timeArr: " + timeArr);
    for (i = 0; i < timeArr.length; i++) {
        regexStr.lastIndex = 0;              // <= HERE!!
        console.log(i + ":" + timeArr[i]);
        console.log("regexResult: " + regexStr.exec(timeArr[i]));
    }
};

parseClassTime("7:55am - 9:10am (TR) 8:10am - 9:00am (W)");
```

Or a shorter way:

```js
var finalArr = [];
var regexStr = /(\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m) - (\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m) \((\w+)\)/g;
var times = "7:55am - 9:10am (TR) 8:10am - 9:00am (W)";
while ((m=regexStr.exec(times)) !== null) {
 finalArr.push([m[1], m[2], m[3]]);
}
console.log(finalArr);
```